# Can you make my code cleaner if possible?

Tags: python

Can you make my code cleaner if possible? The essence of the game is for the player to enter a number greater than the computer. But if the player's number is 50 more than the number chosen by the computer, the player also loses.

This is my code:

```py
from random import randint
#Variables
choice_ai = randint(0,1000)#AI selection
choice_p = int(input("Enter the number: "))#Player selection
choise_win = choice_ai + 50
print(choice_ai)
while True:
    if choice_p == choice_ai:
        print("You and the computer pick the same numbers")
    elif choice_p <= choice_ai or choice_p >= choise_win:
        print("You lose")
    elif choice_p >= choice_ai and choice_p <= choise_win:
        print("You won")
```

Comment: Maybe [codereview.se] is a better choice, but read to tour there before posting.

Comment: Your biggest problem is not cleaning the code, but that you have an infinite loop printing the same line forever.

Comment: The final `elif` is unnecessary; the only way to reach that is for the previous conditions to be false, which already checked for exactly those conditions. Maybe move up the win case so you can use the simplification `if choise_win <= choice_p <= choice_ai:` (though I would also fix the spelling of the first variable).

Comment: Beside checking out Code Review as MegaIng said, consider specifying what exactly you consider dirty in your code. The community could then give you advice on how to solve this. Stackoverflow is not here to do your work for you ;)

Comment: Try Pylint to your code, and correct the choice Spelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had fun doing this :

```py
from random import randint

# Variables
INPUT_MESSAGE = "\nPlease, choose a number : "
OVER_PICK_VALUE = 50

while True:
    while not (raw_input := input(INPUT_MESSAGE)).isdigit():
        print(f"'{raw_input}' is not a number")

    choice_p = int(raw_input)
    choice_ai = randint(0, 1000)
    print(f"The computer chose {choice_ai}.")

    if choice_p == choice_ai:
        print("You and the computer both chose the same value")
    elif choice_ai < choice_p < choice_ai+OVER_PICK_VALUE:
        print("You won")
    else:
        print("You lost")
```

improvements done :

- the user must provide a number
- condition is now clearer
- game continues after the end

what you can add:

- add a score system
- provide feedback as to why the player lost
- give the rule of the game before it begins
- create a GUI for this game
- let the player change the max value for the computer pick

Answer (score 0):

If you use the code above, you get an infinite loop printing always the same result, because nothing changes inside the loop and at each iteration of the loop the same condition is satisfied.
If you want the game to keep going, you should rewrite your code as below:

```py
from random import randint

while True:
   choice_ai = randint(0,1000)#AI selection
   choice_p = int(input("Enter the number: "))#Player selection
   choise_win = choice_ai + 50
   print(choice_ai)

   if choice_p == choice_ai:
        print("You and the computer pick the same numbers")
   elif choice_p <= choice_ai or choice_p >= choise_win:
        print("You lose")
   elif choice_p >= choice_ai and choice_p <= choise_win:
        print("You won")
```

Also, beware that in this way the loop is still infinite. So, if you want the game to finish at some point, you can, for example:

- introduce a counter which keeps track of how many iterations of the loop have been executed and then with an if statement you break the cycle once the counter has reached a certain value;
- or introduce another user input, such as a yes/no question (like "continue?") and then break the cycle if the player inputs "no".